# Error during installation of Dlib library on Windows 10 computer

Tags: python, image-processing, anaconda, face-recognition, dlib

i have a problem about building dlib library on my computer which has windows 10 OS.

Here is my python version :

> C:\Windows\system32>python --version
>   Python 3.7.0

Here is my pip version :

> C:\Windows\system32>pip --version
>
> pip 10.0.1 from C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)

I am trying to download and build the dlib as below :

> pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org --user dlib

The problem starts when pip finished the downloading. After the downloading completes, I get an error message as below which makes me cannot understand what is the actual problem.

NOTE 1 : I already downloaded Anaconda but it also did not solve my problem.

NOTE 2 : As an advice from some Github pages, i also tried the following command but it gave the same error, unfortunately.

> pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host >files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org --user --no-cache-dir >face_recognition

Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/35/8d/e4ddf60452e2fb1ce3164f774e68968b3f110f1cb4cd353235d56875799e/dlib-19.16.0.tar.gz (3.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 3.3MB 159kB/s
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for dlib ... error
  Complete output from command C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\arslanom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2r99u3rh\dlib\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\arslanom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-4nl02lnx --python-tag cp37:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  package init file 'dlib__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  running build_ext
  Building extension for Python 3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 08:04:48) [MSC v.1912 64 bit (AMD64)]
  Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\arslanom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2r99u3rh\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\arslanom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2r99u3rh\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\arslanom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2r99u3rh\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -A x64'
  -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
  CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
    Generator

```
  NMake Makefiles

does not support platform specification, but platform

  x64

was specified.
```

CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
  CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/arslanom/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-2r99u3rh/dlib/build/temp.win-amd64-3.7/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "", line 1, in 
    File "C:\Users\arslanom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2r99u3rh\dlib\setup.py", line 257, in 
      'Topic :: Software Development',
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools__init__.py", line 140, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 202, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\arslanom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2r99u3rh\dlib\setup.py", line 133, in run
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "C:\Users\arslanom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2r99u3rh\dlib\setup.py", line 170, in build_extension
      subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 328, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\Users\arslanom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2r99u3rh\dlib\tools\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\arslanom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2r99u3rh\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\arslanom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2r99u3rh\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

---

Failed building wheel for dlib
  Running setup.py clean for dlib
Failed to build dlib
Installing collected packages: dlib
  Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    Complete output from command C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\arslanom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2r99u3rh\dlib\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\arslanom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-5t8l4109\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'dlib__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Building extension for Python 3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 08:04:48) [MSC v.1912 64 bit (AMD64)]
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\arslanom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2r99u3rh\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\arslanom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2r99u3rh\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\arslanom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2r99u3rh\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -A x64'
    -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
    CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
      Generator

```
    NMake Makefiles

  does not support platform specification, but platform

    x64

  was specified.


CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/arslanom/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-2r99u3rh/dlib/build/temp.win-amd64-3.7/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\arslanom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2r99u3rh\dlib\setup.py", line 257, in <module>
    'Topic :: Software Development',
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 140, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
    return orig.install.run(self)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\arslanom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2r99u3rh\dlib\setup.py", line 133, in run
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "C:\Users\arslanom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2r99u3rh\dlib\setup.py", line 170, in build_extension
    subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 328, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\arslanom\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-2r99u3rh\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\arslanom\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-2r99u3rh\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\arslanom\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-2r99u3rh\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Comment: It could be painlessly if installing using wheel file. https://pypi.org/simple/dlib/

Answer (score 0):

Failed building wheels means that, naively dlib is constructed on c++. Soo for it to be converted to python you'll need Microsoft visual studio c++ package to build the wheel files

Answer (score 0):

Below steps I used to install Dlib on Windows:

**Pre-Requisite**:
1) Install **Python 3.6 64-bit**. If you have Python 32-bit, you need to install Python 3.6 64-bit. Please note, you can not have both Python versions running at same time. If you are intended to run Python 3.6 64-bit, then you need keep Python 3.6 library paths at first position in System and User environment paths.

Visit this tutorial for more info on switching between python versions: [Tutorial on switching between Python Versions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OdIHeg4jj2c)

2) Install cmake library: 
Click link – [Cmake Installer](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.17.0/cmake-3.17.0-win64-x64.msi) and install Cmake. Otherwise, open CMD: install cmake library using pip: `pip install cmake`

Give path of cmake library in System Environment Path and User Path.

e.g. `C:\Program Files\CMake\bin`

In your case it could be different.

3) Install Visual Studio C++ Build Tools: 
Follow this tutorial to install C++ build tools: [Tutorial to install C++ Build Tools](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TC_LPpa7uj0)

It is essential to install C++ compiler to install dlib library

4) Install Numpy library: `pip install numpy`

After successful installation of above libraries/tools, open CMD with “**Run as Administrator**”. Then give command “pip install dlib”

It will install dlib library and it will take time to install. If you have some previous versions of dlib then uninstall them first.

Be patient as it takes lot of time to install this library and also many other ML libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully installed dlib 19.8.1 on Python 3.7 for windows 64bit using
https://www.file-upload.com/qsd69ajuqr2i

Answer (score 0):

I have faced these problems too. You need to install Python 3.6 or 3.7 .
Before that you have to install cmake and set up visual studio as c++ desktop development then install dlib